# Implementing video view in the Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, storyboard

I want to build simple video app thats views a video form youtube links thats users add. 
I didn't find "VideoView" I mean If image view is for image what is UIView for videos.

Comment: use [MPMoviePlayerController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no object in the original library that performs video viewing function. But you can import the `MediaPlayer` framework in your project and add it programmatically.

Here is a Swift example

```
import MediaPlayer

class Step1ViewController: UIViewController {

var moviePlayer: MPMoviePlayerController?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    playVideo()
}

func playVideo() {

    let videoView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.origin.x, self.view.bounds.origin.y, self.view.bounds.width, self.view.bounds.height))

    let pathToEx1 = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("myVideoFile", ofType: "mp4")
    let pathURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(pathToEx1!)
    moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: pathURL)
    if let player = moviePlayer {
        player.view.frame = videoView.bounds
        player.prepareToPlay()
        player.scalingMode = .AspectFill
        videoView.addSubview(player.view)
    }

    self.view.addSubview(videoView)
}
```

}

As for further customisations and app notifications it has a bunch of in-build possibilities. So check it out.

Comment: FYI this MPMoviePlayerController is deprecated

Answer (score 3):

To play video apple has provided MPMovieViewController
see this https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/index.html

and this

http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-play-video-swift/

In youtube Video case we got embedded links are used so for that you will get help from this https://github.com/gilesvangruisen/Swift-YouTube-Player

Comment: > To play video apple has provided MPMovieViewController ... not in cocoa. Apple is a joke.

Answer (score 3):

```
import AVFoundation
import AVKit

class ViewController: UIViewController { 
    var player = AVPlayer()
    var playerController = AVPlayerViewController()

    func playVideo() {     
        let videoURL = NSURL(string: videoUrl)
        player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL! as URL)
        let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
        playerController.player = player
        self.addChildViewController(playerController)

    // Add your view Frame
         playerController.view.frame = self.view.frame

   // Add subview in your view
         self.view.addSubview(playerController.view)

   player.play()
 }

 func stopVideo() {
    player.pause()
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In **Xcode 10** (with a bit less code):

1. In the interface builder (Storyboard), add "**AVKit Player View Controller**"
2. Create a View Controller that derives from **AVPlayerViewController**:

   ```
   import UIKit
   import AVKit

   class VideoPlayerViewController: AVPlayerViewController {

     override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       let videoURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "video", withExtension: "mp4")!
       self.player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL)
     }

     override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
       self.player?.play()
     }
   }
   ```
3. Don't forget to connect this custom class in the storyboard's identity inspector :)

> Note: this example uses video URL pointing to a bundle's resource.

Comment: Note from Apple: `Do not subclass AVPlayerViewController. Overriding this class’s methods is unsupported and results in undefined behavior.` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/avplayerviewcontroller?language=objc