# Inserting a Video from the Photo Library in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have set up the insertion of the image from the photo library and now I am trying to let the user also select a video from the photo library or camera roll in iOS. I have written the following code:-

```
extension ViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

@IBAction func didTapOnImageView(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    
    //call Alert function
    self.showAlert()
    
}

//Show alert to selected the media source type.
private func showAlert() {
    
    var alertStyle = UIAlertController.Style.actionSheet
    
    if (UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad) {
      alertStyle = UIAlertController.Style.alert
    }

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Image Selection", message: "From where you want to pick this image?", preferredStyle: alertStyle)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default, handler: {(action: UIAlertAction) in
        self.getImage(fromSourceType: .camera)
    }))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Photo Album", style: .default, handler: {(action: UIAlertAction) in
        self.getImage(fromSourceType: .photoLibrary)
    }))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .destructive, handler: nil))
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

//get image from source type
private func getImage(fromSourceType sourceType: UIImagePickerController.SourceType) {

    //Check is source type available
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(sourceType) {

        let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePickerController.delegate = self
        imagePickerController.sourceType = sourceType
        imagePickerController.mediaTypes = ["public.image", "public.movie"]
        self.present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

//MARK:- UIImagePickerViewDelegate.
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

    self.dismiss(animated: true) { [weak self] in

        guard let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage else { return }
        //Setting image to your image view
        
        self?.imageView.image = image
        self?.imageView.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        self?.image20 = self?.imageView.image
            
    }
}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

}
```

It works perfectly fine for choosing the image and displaying it, but, now I am able to select the video but, not display it. Could anyone please help on what shall I include in the imagePickerController delegate to obtain the video URL and display it? Thanks for the help! Appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely catch the vide data from your `imagePicker`, like so:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey: Any]) {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true) {
            if let image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage,
                let data = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.8) {
            }
        }
        
        if let videoURL = info[.mediaURL] as? URL {
            do {
                let videoData = try Data(contentsOf: videoURL, options: .mappedIfSafe)
            } catch {
                print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }
```

---

Now, after fetching the `Data` of your selected video file, your next step is to do the research of playing the video data in a view. You can start from this: [Implementing video view in the Storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32368751/implementing-video-view-in-the-storyboard)

But take heed of the age of that link, it's from 2015, but it should still help you out.

Answer (score 0):

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey: Any]) {
    videoURL = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey(rawValue: "UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL")] as? URL
```

}

after getting videoURL you can pass it to AVPlayer to play it.

```
let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL)
let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
playerViewController.player = player
present(playerViewController, animated: true) {
playerViewController.player!.play()
      }
```